# Application Authorization for Registering App and Creating Groups - Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have a Java application running on premise in order to manage Azure app registrations and groups. For that purpose I registered an app and its service principle in Azure.  I am using one of the samples under (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/aad-java-manage-users-groups-and-roles/). I am having trouble about giving right permissions to my app so that it can register other apps, create groups, assign them to groups and do client secret operations. I am receiving 403 unauthorized response. What are least possible Azure AD permissions for these operations? Which steps and options should I take/follow to implement that requirements in portal?

Thanks

**UPDATE 1**
Giving owner right is a big move. So that's not the answer I was looking for.  That's why I am not marking it as a solution for my question but that would definitely work if you are willing to do that. Code also works.
Part of my question was least possible permissions. After experimenting I found that in app permissions:

1. Windows Azure Active Directory->Read Write Directory Data
2. Windows Azure Active Directory->Read Write All Applications
3. Microsoft Graph->Read Write Directory Data
4. Microsoft Graph->Read Write All Domains
5. Microsoft Graph->Read Write All Groups

solved the problem. Active Directory ones allowed me to create app and create group, graph ones allowed me to add app to group. Instead of Graph, adding app as User Access Admin also let me the app to group.

**UPDATE 2**
I am trying to repeat same process with another app. This time although I gave same permissions as I did in Update 1 this time adding new app to group fails with 403. Any idea how this really works? I am really confused...

Comment: You can check the permission requirements from the [Microsoft Graph documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/application_post_applications)

Comment: Thanks @juunas. This page is what I've been looking for. Do you know whether we can add App Permissions programatically or not?

Answer (score 0):

You need create a service principal  and give it `Owner` role to your subscription. You could check the code, the new created user is gived `CONTRIBUTOR` to your subscription. So, your sp need `Owner` role.

```
  // Assign role to AD user, it needs `Owner` role.

   RoleAssignment roleAssignment1 = authenticated.roleAssignments()
           .define(raName1)
            .forUser(user)
            .withBuiltInRole(BuiltInRole.READER)
            .withSubscriptionScope("3b4d41fa-e91d-4bc7-bc11-13d221b3b77d")
           .create();
   System.out.println("Created Role Assignment:");
```

You could do it on Azure Portal.

`<your subscription>--><Access Control>--><Add>`.

[image]

More information about this please refer to this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#assign-application-to-role).

Update:

I test in my lab, you don't need give your sp `Graph` permission, you only need give your sp your subscription `Owner` role. This is my test result.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Shengbao Shiu - MSFT . Do we really need to hit Grant Permissions? What is the effect of it? Is it the concent of Admin?

Comment: And do you guys know whether I can assign Permissions to created App that using my Java application or not?

Comment: Please explain why the SP needs owner rights in the subscription. Having rights in a subscription gives no rights to act on apps in Azure AD. Actually it is dangerous advice to give more permissions than is necessary. If you can tell why that role is needed, I'll revise my comment.

Comment: And Grant permissions gives your app the permissions you require in your Azure AD. Adding permissions as required only specifies that your app needs them, but granting them is another action. That button is one way to grant them.

Comment: @juunas there are some corporate use cases in which portal login is prohibited. That's why companies prefer to build service layers for operations needed. That's the reason for app SPs to manage resources and object. I am not advocating OWNER rights. That's one of the reasons I did not vote for this solution. I am looking for minimum rights. I think Graph API RW Directory and Group RW are the minimum required for this specific case. I'd be glad you can answer whether App Permissions can assigned in my case (using an app). Thanks

Comment: Yes, but in your question you specify a requirement to create things in Azure AD's graph. Having rights in the ARM API does not allow you to do anything in Azure AD so in my opinion it is pointless for the SP to have any permissions in the subscription in this use case.

Comment: @juunas Thanks for your reply. In OP's samples, it does not only create Azure AD users, after create users, the users are granted subscription `CONTRIBUTOR` role. This behavior needs subscription `Onwer` role. If sp does not have this role, it could not access subscription.  I will update my answer.

Comment: @user3499779 You need create a service principal firstly and give subscription `Owner` role.

Comment: @user3499779 When I run this sample, I get some error log, I modify it and works fine for me. Maybe you could check my [code](https://gist.github.com/Walter-Shui/15012584d9bab2861ef631ac1b12b59d)

Comment: @juunas Based on my understanding, OP's examples don't use Grap API to create users. So, it does not need Grap API permission. Also, I remove sp's all permission on Portal, the code also works for me.

Comment: Alright my bad, I thought it is about creating users and assigning them to apps in Azure AD. Indeed if you need to assign users into roles in the Azure portal, permissions are needed on the subscription or a resource group.

Comment: Part of that management layer's role is to register other apps, too. That's why I need to create apps and assign them to user groups. As you know to use some resources applications have to be authenticated and authorized for the Azure resource. (ex: key vault).

Comment: @user3499779 It is a different question, maybe you could ask a new question.

Comment: Pleas see Update 2. I thought I solved it and wanted to repeat the steps with a new account but add group didn't work